# Can't figure out how to fix null error

Tags: ms-access, vba

For my form, almost all paper forms should come with an ID that you enter into one field. However, a few forms will come with no IDs, and I want to generate into a different field an ID number based on the user entering the information.

What I want it to do is to create a 4-digit number, where the first digit is from the field usernum, and the last 3 digits are just sequentially counting.

The first time they press the button, nothing is in the usernum field yet, and I think this may be the cause of my runtime 94 error?

below is my code and the error line

```
Private Sub Command100_Click()
'on click of button InsightId is generated
Me.idnum = NewInsightID()
End Sub

Public Function NewInsightID() As Long


Dim lngNextID As Long

'Find highest  ID in the test table and add 1
lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum) + 1
'ABOVE IS THE LINE WITH ERRORS

'Assign function the value of the Next ID
NewInsightID = lngNextID

End Function
```

I have tried various workarounds but none have worked

below is what i've tried and hasn't worked:

```
lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + 1 + NZ(DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum),0)

lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + 1 + Nz(DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Nz(Me.usernum, 0)), 0)

lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + 1 + DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Nz(Me.usernum, 0))
```

EDIT 2:
Okay, have made process. Sort of have it working, except for two things--for some reason it won't start at 001, only 002. After that, it does move incrementally by one.
The main thing is an error if usernum is blank. Again, I don't anticipate this ever being the case, but when it comes to data entry I think it's best to assume the dumbest possible users, and since I'm going to be on vacation when this database is used I don't want to get any calls about errors. I'm trying to do it so that if usernum is blank, they get a message that tells them the error and cancels the sub, but for some reason it isn't working, and then later in the code i get the error message Run time error 3075 missing operator in query expression 'usernum='. I assumed doing a message box to fix that would solve the problem, but I can't get the message box to work.

```
   Private Sub Command100_Click()
'on click of button InsightId is generated
If usernum = Null Then
    Beep
    MsgBox ("you cannot leave usernum blank")
    Cancel = True
Else: Me.idnum = NewInsightID()
End If
End Sub

Public Function NewInsightID() As Long


Dim lngNextID As Long


'Find highest  ID in the test table and add 1

   If DMax("idnum", "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum) = Null Then
        lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000 + 1)
    Else:
        lngNextID = 1 + Nz(DMax("idnum", "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum), Me.usernum * 1000 + 1)
    End If

'Assign function the value of the Next ID
NewInsightID = lngNextID

End Function
```

EDIT3:
aaah I solved it incredible!!

```
Private Sub Command100_Click()
'on click of button InsightId is generated
If IsNull(Me.usernum) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox ("you cannot leave usernum blank")
    Cancel = True
Else: Me.idnum = NewInsightID()
End If
End Sub

Public Function NewInsightID() As Long


Dim lngNextID As Long


'Find highest  ID in the test table and add 1

   If DMax("idnum", "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum) = Null Then
    lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000 + 1)
    Else:
    lngNextID = 1 + Nz(DMax("idnum", "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum), Me.usernum * 1000)
    End If

    'Assign function the value of the Next ID
    NewInsightID = lngNextID

End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean that the user doesn' t have any records in the test table yet, but that they have an ID themselves?  What you want to do is something like "If DMax(.....) Is Null Then lngNextID = Me.usernum*1000) + 1 Else lngNextID = Right(DMax(....), 3) + 1"  However, if there are IDs that the user has entered that are bigger than the ones created by this process, you could run into some issues.

Comment: Basically each user (person entering data) is assigned a one digit number, which is usernum. Usernum is the first digit for the calculated ID, which is idnum. idnum will be blank for all users until the first time they press the button to indicate they need to generate one. I will try OpiesDad solution and see how it works

Comment: still giving me a null error @OpiesDad. with the code `If DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum) Is Null Then lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000 + 1)
    Else: lngNextID = Right(DMax([idnum], "test", ["usernum=" & Me.usernum]), 3) + 1` the if through then is highlighted

Comment: Just as a comment, the line "Cancel = True" that you have won't do anything.  This line is used in specific events that have Cancel as a parameter such as the _Close event.  Setting it to True would prevent the object from closing.  In your code all you are doing is creating a new variable named Cancel and assigning it the value True as the Click event has no such parameter.

Comment: thanks! I've cleared that part up already--for some reason I've had a much harder time finding resources about msgbox syntax and examples than I have for other access vba stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is close:

```
lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + 1 + NZ(DMax([idnum], "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum), 0)
```

but the first parameter of `DMax` (the fieldname or expression) is a string too:

```
lngNextID = (Me.usernum * 1000) + 1 + NZ(DMax("idnum", "test", "usernum=" & Me.usernum), 0)
```